# Pandas concat 2 dataframes combining each row

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I am struggled with this.

I have:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.Series([0, 1, 2, 3])
df2= pd.Series(["A", "B", "C", "D"])

df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0)
```

my result is:

```
0
1
2
3 
A
B
C
D
```

and I need the following output:

```
0
A
1
B 
2
C
3
D
```

Comment: It's very unclear what you are asking...

Answer (score 1):

Add [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort_index.html) with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) for avoid duplicated index values:

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
print (df3)
0    0
1    A
2    1
3    B
4    2
5    C
6    3
7    D
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

By using `np.insert`

```
   pd.Series(np.insert(df1.astype(str).values,np.arange(len(df1))+1,df2.values))

Out[1105]: 
0    0
1    A
2    1
3    B
4    2
5    C
6    3
7    D
dtype: object
```